# "ng" module is not defined

Tags: angularjs, module, typescript, definitelytyped

I'm using typescript with `amd` modules and i have installed the angular typings from DefinitelyTyped.

The typings have the following code:

`// Collapse angular into ng
import ng = angular;`

This lets me use the `ng` module from inside my other typescript files, but when compiled the generated javascript doesn't have the `var ng = angular` line that would be generated from the `import ng = angular` typescript code line , so obviously the code fails telling me that ng is not defined.

Do I have to put `import ng = angular`  manually on on every file or there is a better solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ng` line in the typings file is there for convenience of accessing types (FWIW this is a bad idea, the definition file author should have restructured the file so you don't see `ng` as a variable).

You should be referencing values from `angular` via the `angular` variable. If it's really a big deal to be able to write `ng.module` instead of `angular.module`, then you'll need the `import` statement in your implementation files.